# How to display two string array value in list view in android

Tags: android

I have two string array value for two column in list view .how to display two string array value in list view? and if use click row i need to update the value can anybody tell how to do

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use below link of custom listview

[Custom Listview](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)